# Keras vs TensorFlow2 Implementation of Multilayer Perceptron

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have the following implementation of a simple multilayer perceptron model as below:

```
from keras.models import Model 
from keras.layers import Input 
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.utils import plot_model

visible = Input(shape=(10,))
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(visible)
hidden2 = Dense(20, activation='relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden2)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden3)

my_model_keras = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
```

and plot_model() function returns the following graph:

[image]

I then attempt at implementing the same model in Tensorflow2 as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class TensorflowModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TensorflowModel, self).__init__()

        self.visible = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,))
        self.hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
        self.hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20)
        self.hidden3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
        self.final = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, x, training=False):
        x = self.visible(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.hidden1(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.hidden3(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.final(x)

        return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)

my_model_tf = TensorflowModel()
```

However, plot_model() function returns this graph (different than above graph):

[image]

Is there something wrong with my implementation of Tensorflow2 model?

Comment: are you sure about returining tf.nn.sigmoid(x) instead of self.final(x) ? can you add the plot_model() function so other can help you better - I am looking at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#layers_are_recursively_composable

Answer (score 0):

The models should be the same. I suspect the difference in the plot is due to the fact that you're using tf.nn operations rather than layer activations as in the first implementation. The plot_model implementation might not interpret the dense layer nodes as adjacent because of that.

Comment: I am not sure if the two models are the same.  When I call model.summary() for the tf version, it throws the following error: `ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling build() or calling fit() with some data, or specify an input shape argument in the first layer for automatic build`